# How can I send request using arbitrary method defined by the user in the Python requests

Tags: python-requests

I need sending request to arbitrary method without standard method like "GET", "POST", "TRACE" ..

How can I do this?

Is it possible to implement additional methods by inheriting a class within the module?

This is to cause an error page for security testing.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy enough according to the Requests documentation:

```py
http_verb = "WHATEVER_YOU_WANT"
r = requests.request(http_verb, url)
```

This can be used exactly the same as `requests.get`, but there's the added first parameter that is the HTTP verb.